# Removing children recursively from DefaultMutableTreeNode doesn't update in frame correctly

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a JTree, `projectView`:

```
projectView = new JTree(projectViewTop);
projectView.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
projectView.setSize(250, getHeight());
projectView.setLocation(0, 0);
projectView.setVisible(true);
projectView.addKeyListener(this);
add(projectView);
```

Where `projectViewTop` is the main node (`DefaultMutableTreeNode`) of the JTree:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode projectViewTop = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Project");
```

The `projectViewTop` has a couple children nodes, which also contain sub-children as well (projectViewTop is the 'Project [My project]' node):

[image]

At one point, I need to clear every child of the `projectViewTop` node. I created this method to clear them recursively:

```
public void clearNode(DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
    for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildCount(); i++) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) node.getChildAt(i);
        clearNode(child);
    }
    node.removeAllChildren();
}
```

However, when I run this method, the content does not get cleared visually. This is what happens to the JTree display:

[image]

On the other hand, if I collapse the main node, it clears everything properly (it seems the visuals only get updated when I collapse the main node). **How can I prevent 'dirt' children nodes staying on the main node when clearing it?**

Comment: @AndrewThompson I mean, I tried to make this as straightforward as possible, because the problem is probably a missing statement/a mistake on my end. If you think I should change something, please let me know?

Comment: You need to notify the `TreeModel` that the structure has changed, `DefaultTreeModel` has a [`nodesWereRemoved`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#nodesWereRemoved(javax.swing.tree.TreeNode,%20int[],%20java.lang.Object[])) method which you can use, if you're using a `DefaultTreeModel`, the nodes themselves know nothing about the model ... yep, it's all fun stuff

Comment: @MadProgrammer I used the `nodeStructureChanged` method instead, it does that stuff all by itself. Pretty convenient. If you don't mind, you can write the answer and I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: `nodeStructureChanged` is a poor choice, as it will cause the ENTIRE tree to be re-rendered, whereas `nodesWereRemoved` will only effect the nodes you changed

Comment: @AndrewThompson I added everything I thought might be related to the issue, I removed and cleared up stuff that shouldn't be there (and shouldn't affect it), I explained the problem with pictures, the problem is understandable because it is obviously not an expected outcome, and the issue *is* reproducible. I think this fits with the MCV. Now, I know the issue is not 'self contained' directly, but that would infringe the 'Short' rule, because writing a whole GUI in a question when it is not related to the whole process of the problem. I tried my best, but linking me to that post didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to notify the `TreeModel` that the structure has changed.

For whatever reason (I'm assuming it's an optimisation choice), the nodes have no (direct) connection to the `TreeModel`, they are kind of like two models working together, but where one isn't talking to the other ... yes, this is very annoying

So when you modify the "node" tree, you need to notify the `TreeModel` and will cause an update to the `JTree` ...

`DefaultTreeModel` has a [nodesWereRemoved](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#nodesWereRemoved(javax.swing.tree.TreeNode,%20int[],%20java.lang.Object[])) method which you can use, if you're using a `DefaultTreeModel`.

Comment: @mKorbel Sorry, no pictures today :P